# Bragg scattering off an array of wiggly lines

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, scattering, amorphous-solids

I'm currently working through some problems in Chaiken and Lubensky and I found that my understanding of scattering theory is weaker than I thought. So I could use a sanity check on this problem

Problem 2.6 asks to calculate the Bragg peaks from scattering off an array of lines described by $$y_p(x) = pl + u_1 \cos[(2\pi x/l) \sin(2\pi/5)]\cos[2\pi p \cos(2\pi/5)] \\ + u_2 \cos[(2\pi x/l) \sin(4\pi/5)] \cos[2\pi p \cos(4\pi/5)]$$

I recognize that the $u_1$ oscillations are periodic with wavelength $l/\sin(2\pi/5)$ and the $u_2$ oscillation with wavelength $l/\sin(4\pi/2)$ so the ratio of wavelengths is $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

So $l$ is an overall length scale (set to 1 for simplicity) and $u_1,u_2$ control the amplitudes of incommensurate oscillations.

If $U_2=0$, the lines make a lattice thats periodic in the $x$ direction $\vec{T}_x=\frac{1}{\sin(2\pi/5)}$ and quasiperiodic in the $y$ direction caused by incommensurate oscillations of wavelength $\vec{T}_y = 1 $ $\vec{T}'_y = \frac{1}{\cos(2\pi/5)}$

Likewise, if $U_1=0$, the lines make a lattice thats periodic in the $x$ direction $\vec{T}'_x=\frac{1}{\sin(4\pi/5)}$ and quasiperiodic in the $y$ direction caused by incommensurate oscillations of wavelength $\vec{T}_y =1$ $\vec{T}''_y = \frac{1}{\cos(4\pi/5)}$

So with all the terms together, there is a multiply incommensurate lattice with translation vectors $\vec{T}_x$, $\vec{T}_x'$, $\vec{T}_y$,$\vec{T}_y'$,$\vec{T}_y''$.

Here's where I get a little uncertain:

Assuming that $U_1\approx U_2 \approx 1$, there would be 4 sets of main bragg peaks, at wave-vectors corresponding to the dual lattices generated independently by the pairs $(T_x, T_y ) , (T_x, T'_y), (T'_x,T_y), (T'_x,T''_y)$ and then satellite brag peaks generated by the differences $T_x-T_x' , T_y-T'_y, T_y-T''_y,T'_y-T''_y$.
But how do these difference vectors generate dual lattice vectors?  In 1-D it is easy: each incommensurate length scale requires another integer  $q= n_1 \frac{2\pi}{a_1} + n_2 \frac{2\pi}{a_2} + n_2 \frac{2\pi}{a_2} + ... $

Comment: Any progress on this problem?